# VideoView on Viewpager, stopping video when switching page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have a viewpager with different fragments, one of these has a videoview in it. If I switch page when the video is playing then it remaings playing even when I'm on a different page. I tried implementing an OnPageChangeListener for the ViewPager like this:

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if(position!=mAdapter.getCount()-1){
                    MultimediaFragment frag = (MultimediaFragment)mAdapter.getItem(position+1);
                    frag.onPageIsChanged();
                }

                if(position != 0){
                    MultimediaFragment frag = (MultimediaFragment)mAdapter.getItem(position-1);
                    frag.onPageIsChanged();
                }


            }
```

With onPageIsChanged() being a method of my own which tries to tell my videoview attribute to stop and hide controls:

```
public void onPageIsChanged() {
        if(mVideoView!=null){
            if(mVideoView.isPlaying()){
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
            mMedia.hide();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that mVideoView is always null, even when it's playing on the background. This videoview is created on the OnCreateView method of the fragment, but shouldn't it remain set to my mVideoView field until fragment is destroyed?

Comment: Hi there, I want to ask if you solve this problem, can you give me some help, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by overriding the method:

```
void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
```

Don't know if that's the proper way though.

Comment: Hi there, I need some help please!, I use setUserVisibleHint to stop video when it's not visible but when return to video page directly the video not play how can I solve this problem??

Comment: How does this solve the problem?    And where do you set this?  Plus this method never gets called when I swipe the pager.

Answer (score 7):

You have to override setUserVisibleHint method in a fragment where u play video.

```
   public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
   {       
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);                         
     if (this.isVisible())
     {               
        if (!isVisibleToUser)   // If we are becoming invisible, then...
        {  
          //pause or stop video
        }

        if (isVisibleToUser) // If we are becoming visible, then...
        {                               
            //play your video               
        }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: I used this method in onResume and onPause methods in my fragment. So this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your mAdapter.getItem is creating a new fragment each time.  This will cause the video view to always be null.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    SparseArray<Fragment>fragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment frag = fragments.get(position);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if(frag != null){
            return frag;
        }
        fragments.put(position, frag);
        return frag;
    }
}
```